# grid view is not showing result

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview, drop-down-menu

I want to bind `GridView` at run time when the `DataSource` is selected and when the user select a option from a `DropDownList`. But the selected table or connection is not made properly.
Please check the following code and give me the appropriate solution.

```
    public partial class index : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        string option = "";
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            option = selectProductdropdown.SelectedValue;
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label2.Text = option;
            if (option == "Books")
            {

                Label3.Text = option;
                conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["booksconnectionstring"].ConnectionString;
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from books", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                SqlDataAdapter reader = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                DataSet s = new DataSet();
                reader.Fill(s);
                GridView1.DataSource = s;
                GridView1.DataBind();
                conn.Close();
            }
```

Comment: Can you put here your error message?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your page_load event, where you are assigning a value to option. When you click the button, the page_load will call again and your value will reset.

it should be...

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if(!Page.IsPostBack)
        option = selectProductdropdown.SelectedValue;
    }
```

OR it would be better if you do like..

```
if (selectProductdropdown.SelectedValue == "Books")
```

Answer (score 0):

because you are probably emptying option at each page load.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the public variable **string option = "";**

Instead define the same in the **Click Event** and get the selected value there

```
option = selectProductdropdown.SelectedValue;// move to click event
```

Because when the button is clicked the dropdown would be reset (assuming you have not shown the dropdown bind code here)

Comment: i move it to button click event. but still the result is not showing.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        option = selectProductdropdown.SelectedValue;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You had omitted this line:

```
cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Place it between the statements, like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from books", conn);
cmd.ExecuteReader();  // <-- HERE
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```